# duplicate perl expression inserted in command

Tags: gnu-parallel

Does this make sense?  I need to "edit" the slot to turn it into a GPU board number but it puts more than one copy of the Perl result in the parallel command if I use more than one input list.

Is there a correct way to get just one instance of the perl substitution while keeping the ":::" syntax?

```
GNU parallel 20230822
Copyright (C) 2007-2023 Ole Tange, http://ole.tange.dk and Free Software
Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
GNU parallel comes with no warranty.

Web site: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel

When using programs that use GNU Parallel to process data for publication
please cite as described in 'parallel --citation'.
bash-4.2$ parallel --dry-run --jobs 3 echo {= '$_=slot()-1' =} ::: 1 2 3 4
echo 0
echo 1
echo 2
echo 0
bash-4.2$ parallel --dry-run --jobs 3 echo {= '$_=slot()-1' =} ::: 1 2 3 4 ::: a b c
echo 0 0
echo 1 1
echo 2 2
echo 0 0
echo 1 1
echo 2 2
echo 0 0
echo 1 1
echo 2 2
echo 0 0
echo 1 1
echo 2 2
bash-4.2$ parallel --dry-run --jobs 3 echo {= '$_=slot()-1' =} ::: 1 2 3 4 ::: a b c ::: 1
echo 0 0 0
echo 1 1 1
echo 2 2 2
echo 1 1 1
echo 0 0 0
echo 2 2 2
echo 1 1 1
echo 0 0 0
echo 2 2 2
echo 1 1 1
echo 0 0 0
echo 2 2 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled across a way to get the behavior I expected:

```
bash-4.2$ parallel --dry-run --jobs 3 echo {=1 '$_=slot()-1' =} ::: 1 2 3 4 ::: a b c
echo 1
echo 0
echo 2
echo 1
echo 0
echo 2
echo 1
echo 0
echo 2
echo 1
echo 0
echo 2
```

Not exactly sure why, but it works.

Comment: This is due to positional replacement strings. I think it is clear to you that `{}` will insert a value from all input sources. If you have 3 input sources, `{}` will insert 3 values. `{2}`, however, will only insert the value from the second input source. `{= =}` works like `{}`, and `{=2 =}` works like `{2}`. So `{=1 '$_=slot()-1' =}` takes a value from input source 1 and replaces that with `slot()-1`. If you have 2 input sources the result will be exactly the same if you use `{=2 '$_=slot()-1' =}` because you overwrite the value from the input source.

Comment: I guess I was expecting it so substitute three values once, not one value each 3 times.  Just my flawed expectation since I'm new to the Perl part of parallel.

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Maybe it is more clear to you if you run: `parallel echo {= s/a/A/ =} 2={=2 s/a/A/ =} ::: a1 a2 a3 ::: ba bb bc ::: ca cb cc`